# Find number of solutions of the equation $x^4-1=e^x$.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

I tried making a rough plot and trying to find number of intersections and got that either number of solutions will be $1$ or $3$.
But I am confused how to check which is the case out of the following two:
[image: 1 solutions in this case]

This is graph of $x^2-1$ and $e^x$ which give only one solution.

And below is actual graph of $x^4-1$ which $e^x$:
[image]

**So I want to know how to decide which graph will be the case here
**without** putting values of $x$ and check(as it works here as small values but may not in other cases). I want to know a general approach.
Like if we have to find solutions of $x^{12}-1 = e^{3.25x}$, how do we
know what will be the case.**

Comment: $x\approx -1.0761, x\approx 1.54401,
x\approx 8.61283$

Comment: @Moo: Can you explain a bit more.

Comment: @Moo How that helps?

Comment: $x^4-1$ and $e^x$ can have only a fixed number of intersections. How can you get either 1 or 3? Probably you mean something different (e.g. $x^{2n}-1=e^x$)

Comment: @user, Yeah I meant that only. Like I was saying that it would be one of 1 or 3.

Comment: Then you should change at least the title of the question.

Comment: Instead graph $e^x-x^4+1$.

Comment: OP is asking for a way to tell which of the two cases (1 intersection or 3, indicated by the graphs) we're in without graphing.

Comment: Let $r(x) = (x^n - 1)/e^{a x}$. Show that $r'(x) = -(a x^n - n x^{n - 1} - a)/e^{a x}$ has exactly one positive root. It follows that $r(x)$ increases from $r(0) = -1$ to $r_{\text {max}}$ and then decreases to $r(\infty) = 0$. The equation $e^{a x} = x^n - 1$ doesn't have positive roots if $r_{\text {max}} < 1$ and has exactly two positive roots if $r_{\text {max}} > 1$. For your examples, using $e < 3$ is enough to verify that $r_{\text {max}} > r(2) > 1$. The critical value of $a$ is
$$a_n = W^{1/n}(n e^{-n}) (W(n e^{-n}) + n)^{1 - 1/n},$$
where $W$ is the Lambert W-function.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hand-wavy idea that someone can flesh out if they please.

Given a positive integer $n$ and positive real number $a$, the task is to find out how many solutions $x^{2n} -1 = e^{ax}$ has.  Replace $e^{ax}$ by its Maclauren polynomial of sufficient degree subtract the left side from the right:

$$2 + ax +\frac{(ax)^2}{2!} + \cdots + \left(\frac{a^{2n}}{(2n)!}-1\right){x^{2n}} +\cdots = 0.$$

By Descartes'Rule of Signs, if $\frac{a^{2n}}{(2n)!}-1$ is positive, there are no sign changes and hence no positive zeroes.  If it's negative then there are two sign changes and so there might be two zeroes.

I checked this out on the suggested $x^{12} - 1=e^{3.25x}$.  There are 3 solutions in this case and we have $\frac{a^{2n}}{(2n)!}-1 = -.997\ldots$.  Then I tried $x^{12} -1= e^{6x}.$  In this case $\frac{a^{2n}}{(2n)!}-1 = 3.544\ldots$, and the graph shows there is only one solution.

So I believe that the sign of $\frac{a^{2n}}{(2n)!}-1$ is a good indicator of whether there are one or three zeroes.